# Display table in jsp with servlet

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I can't get the table to appear on the jsp. Could you please take a look at my code, and tell me what I'm doing wrong? Thank you!

This is the java-code:

```
@WebServlet(name = "TurvingControllerServlet", urlPatterns = {"/TurvingController"})
@MultipartConfig

public class TurvingControllerServlet extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private static String INSERT_OR_EDIT = "/turvingen.jsp";
private static String LIST_TURVING = "/waarnemingen.jsp";
private Turving turv;

public TurvingControllerServlet() {
    super();
    turv = new Turving();
}

@Override
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    String forward="";
    String action = request.getParameter("action");

    if (action.equalsIgnoreCase("delete")){
        String id = request.getParameter("id");
        turv.wisTurving();
        forward = LIST_TURVING;
        request.setAttribute("turving", turv.toonAlleTurvingen());    
    }  else if (action.equalsIgnoreCase("waarnemingen")){
        forward = LIST_TURVING;
        request.setAttribute("turving", turv.toonAlleTurvingen());
    } else {
        forward = INSERT_OR_EDIT;
    }

    RequestDispatcher view = request.getRequestDispatcher(forward);
    view.forward(request, response);
}
 @Override
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    Turving turving = new Turving();

    turving.setId(request.getParameter("id"));
    turving.setDatum(request.getParameter("datum"));
    turving.setTijd(request.getParameter("tijd"));
    turving.setPlaats(request.getParameter("plaats"));
    turving.setSpotternaam(request.getParameter("spotternaam"));
    turving.setVogelsoort(request.getParameter("vogelsoort"));
    turving.schrijfTurving();
    String id = request.getParameter("spotternaam");

    RequestDispatcher view = request.getRequestDispatcher(LIST_TURVING);
    request.setAttribute("turvingen", turv.toonAlleTurvingen());
    view.forward(request, response);
}
}
```

And this the JSP: (part of it)

```
<table border=1>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Datum</th>
            <th>Tijd</th>
            <th>Plaats</th>
            <th>Spotternaam</th>
            <th>Vogelsoort</th>

        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <c:forEach  items="${turvingen}" var="turving">
            <tr>
                <td><c:out value="${turving.datum}" /></td>
                <td><c:out value="${turving.tijd}" /></td>
                <td><c:out value="${turving.plaats}" /></td>
                <td><c:out value="${turving.spotternaam}" /></td>
                <td><c:out value="${turving.vogelsoort}" /></td>


            </tr>
        </c:forEach>
    </tbody>
          </table>
```

I really hope you can help me, I don't see where I'm going wrong...

Answer (score 0):

Your attribute names don't match.

The attribute you set is called `turving`. The one you are requesting is called `turvingen`.

Answer (score 0):

From the codes in the servlet,

```
RequestDispatcher view = request.getRequestDispatcher(LIST_TURVING);
request.setAttribute("turvingen", turv.toonAlleTurvingen());
view.forward(request, response);
```

If `turv.toonAlleTurvingen()` returns the `list`. then you need to intialise and populate the list in the servlet before you forward it with the request.

so you need to do it like ,

```
List list=new ArrayList();
list=turv.toonAlleTurvingen();
```

then forward the list to the attribute as ,

```
request.setAttribute("turvingen", list);
```

Hope this helps !!